# How to wrap material ui component to redux form component for Field?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to understand how can I wrap `material ui` component into the `redux-form` Field component?

```
<FormControl variant='outlined' className={classes.textField}>
            <InputLabel
              ref={ref => {
                this.InputLabelRef = ref
              }}
              htmlFor='outlined-county-simple'
            >
              {this.state.countryName}
            </InputLabel>
            <Select
              value={this.state.country}
              onChange={this.handleChangeCountry}
              input={
                <OutlinedInput
                  labelWidth={this.state.labelWidth}
                  name='country'
                />
              }
            >
              {isData(country) ? country.map((entity, index) => {
                return (
                  <MenuItem value={entity.code} key={`county-${index}`}>{entity.country}</MenuItem>)
              }) : null}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
```

As result I want to get data from this component to redux-form store, which case are user will select. I can make it by using change function from redux , but I don't think that this is correct way to work. I have example how to wrap TextField component into redux form component

```
import mapProps from 'recompose/mapProps'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'

export default mapProps(({
  input: {name, onChange, value},
  meta: {touched, error},
  helperText,
  ...restProps
}) => ({
  error: !!(touched && error),
  fullWidth: true,
  helperText: (touched && error) ? error : helperText,
  margin: 'normal',
  onChange: event => onChange(event.target.value),
  value,
  ...restProps
}))(TextField)
```

Comment: I don't really understand your code, it seems too complicated, why not using this library https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui so you can use material ui component into the redux-form Field

Answer (score 0):

This should work. We can just pass the component to the Field as shown in the code snippet, which here in my case is the renderSelectField.

```html
 <Field
          name="favoriteColor"
          component={renderSelectField}
          label="Favorite Color"
        >
```